# Dynamics Data Export Service to Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, data-export, azure-sql-managed-instance

I understand that we can set up Dynamics data export service to Azure SQL database however can we do that for Azure SQL Managed Instance instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/data-export-service) says

> Data Export is an add-on service made available as a Dynamics 365 (online) solution that adds the ability to replicate Dynamics 365 (online) data to a Microsoft Azure SQL Database store in a customer-owned Microsoft Azure subscription. **The supported target destinations are Microsoft Azure SQL Database and Microsoft Azure SQL Server on Microsoft Azure virtual machines**.